# Start Java Application with Error Message The Value of the File specifier in an Open statement is invalid (unit=12)

Tags: java, c#, jar

I will start a excecuteable Java File (.jar) from my C# Application.
It works fine but some times I get a Message from Java Runtime:

> Headline from the Messagebox:Fortran
>
> Text: The Value of the File specifier in an Open statement is invalid
>   (unit=12)

The same problem when I try it over a BAT script.

My command looks like this: `java -d32 -jar CPREngine.jar`

Anybody knows this problem and can help me please?